# Print a list of all controllers for the project?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Is there a way to print out a list of all the controllers associated with a project? I've done some searching around but haven't had a lot of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use App::objects('Controller') to find out which Objects Controller are used within your application. Find out more about App class at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up doing this

`$controllpull = App::objects('Controller');`

Then you can just do a `print_r($controllpull);`